# bootstrap datepicker orientation syntax for placement of the datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Does anyone know the syntax for setting the [orientation property](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/README.md#orientation) orientation property for the bootstrap datepicker?

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dp3").datepicker({
        orientation: 'top right'
    });
});
```

Datepicker works fine but can't change the orientation all, any help would be appreciated.

Html looks like:

```
<div class="control-group">                                         
    <label class="control-label" for="birthday">Birthday</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            <input class="date-input-large" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /controls -->               
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do you have any overriding CSS? The orientation seems to work fine here: http://www.bootply.com/61141

Comment: I just added your code to my site and it didnt work so its something else, you mentioned css can mess this up?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.The picker opens in the top of the page away from the data field

Comment: Can't use 'orientation' property, me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap datapicker plugin just support left orientation. You can check the original [code here](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L274). However, it has some smartness to keep it in view.

All you can use is:

```
$("#dp3").datepicker({
    orientation: 'left'
});
```

orientation as `right`, `top` are not supported.